# How to give unique numbers to a set of repeated column values in MS- Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column field called State and it contains 38 different states, which keeps repeating( total column count is 154000). I have sorted the column field. Now I want to add another column named State id,  which should function in such a way that for each State there should be a unique State id

For example, if 1st state is repeating 5000 times and 2nd state is repeating 25000 times - the State Id  value should have 1 repeating 5000 times for 1st state and 2 repeating 25000 times for 2nd State and the same logic should be applicable for other states as well

Is it possible using excel?

Comment: If Possible Please add a screen print of your input and expeced Output

Answer (score 0):

you could set up a lookup table on another tab

state    id
Texas     1
Delaware  2
Kentucky  3

then in your main list use =vlookup formula to match the state names and return the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an if to verify if that state already have an id and then create a new one. All this inside a loop, of course.